# ansible loop over list and dictionary at the same time

Tags: loops, ansible

I am writing a playbook that ensure nodes appear in `/etc/fstab`.

I am using loops to prevent code duplication.

The logic is first to check if the line appears using grep (with perl regex because it is a multi line) and store the results in a register.

Then I want to add only the lines that are not in fstab file. To achieve that I need to loop over list (the register with the grep return codes) and a dictionary (that contains the fstab entries).

I am having errors with the parallel loop. I tried to follow [these](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-parallel-sets-of-data) steps.

`One or more undefined variables: 'str object' has no attribute 'item'`

tasks/fstab.yaml:

```
---
- name: Make dirs
  sudo: yes
  file: path={{ item.value }} state=directory
  with_dict:
    "{{ fstab.paths }}"

- name: Check whether declared in fstab
  sudo: no
  command: grep -Pzq '{{ item.value }}' /etc/fstab
  register: is_declared
  with_dict:
    "{{ fstab.regexs }}"

- name: Add the missing entries
  sudo: yes
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/fstab line="{{ item.1.item.value }}"
  when: item.0.rc == 1
  with_together:
    - "{{ is_declared.results }}"
    - "{{ fstab.entries }}"
```

vars/main.yml:

```
---
fstab:
  paths:
    a: "/mnt/a"
    b: "/mnt/b"

  regexs:
    a: '\n# \(a\)\nfoo1'
    b: '\n# \(b\)\nfoo2'

  entries:
    a: "\n# (a)\nfoo1"
    b: "\n# (b)\nfoo2"
```

- I am not using template on purpose (I want to add entries to existing files and not to over write them).

---

UPDATE: I see ansible has module "mount" which deals with fstab. However I am still looking for a solution to this issue because I might be needed it again later on.

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple ideas as to why your original approach was failing, but let's scratch that for a moment. It looks like you're overcomplicating things- why not use a complex list var to tie it all together, and use the regexp arg to the lineinfile module instead of a separate regex task? (though your sample data should work fine even without the regexp param) Something like:

```
---
- name: Make dirs
  sudo: yes
  file: path={{ item.path }} state=directory
  with_items: fstab

- name: Add the missing entries
  sudo: yes
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/fstab line={{ item.entry }} regexp={{ item.regex }}
  with_items: fstab
```

---

```
fstab:
  - path: /mnt/a
    regex: '\n# \(a\)\nfoo1'
    entry: "\n# (a)\nfoo1"
  - path: /mnt/b
    regex: '\n# \(b\)\nfoo2'
    entry: '\n# (b)\nfoo2'
```

Comment: Your solution would be good for one liners. lineinfile regexp doesn't work on multiple lines patterns. That's why I did that separation.